# Flutter is unable to load assets with German umlauts

Tags: flutter, flutter-image

When the file has an umlaut in its name Flutter cannot load the file. Is there an option it fix that without changing the name of the file?

An example error message is:

> The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
> Unable to load asset: assets/images/Zähne.png

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file from `Zähne.png` to `Zaehne.png`

Comment: Thanks! That would work surely but I wonder if there's a way to do it differently without renaming the file